# Need advice regarding which DB should I use for my flutter app

Tags: mysql, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, custom-backend

I've a project where employees would have to report using the app so basically there will be following features in app login, reporting and only view the products of the company through app.

Now, the problem is that I need to import loads of employee data and that's where I am getting confused because I know how to import data from CSV files to SQL DB but I don't have any idea about how to do the same in firebase.
Also I couldn't figure out the pricing difference between both which one would be more feasible in terms of price ?

If possible please try to generalize the answer in two parts :

1. Pricing
2. Ease of use on basis of functionality provided by respective packages at pub.dev

So guys, which DB shall I use for it ? SQL or firebase as per my requirement ?

It would be really helpful of y'all if anyone can guide me through some insightful links to blogs or articles which can guide me in setting up a proper backend for my flutter app.
Thanks !

Comment: It depends on your requirements. If its you need a database that can do complex things like aggregation in mongodb, you shouldn't use firebase. Based on the information you provided, I think firebase would be enough for you. Usually, firebase real-time database would be a better choice compared to cloud firestore. Scroll down here to take a test: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore . For switching from sql to nosql, you'd have to learn how nosql differs from sql and how it stores data to be able to use any of the two firebase databases. There are many tutorials online.

Comment: Firebase has generous limits on its free tier. I don't think you'll use more resources than its free tier based on your use case. It's the easiest to implement since you don't have to create your own backend api for storing data in the database. It's also one of the easiest to use because of the firebase libraries in pub.dev.

Comment: "I don't have any idea about how to do the same in firebase" Did you google it? It seems you can get an idea in about 30 seconds, some ideas are even SO question/Answer pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Using firebase would reduce a lots of hard work, using firebase you can continuously listen to changes made in the database because it provides you a stream of data and subscribing would refresh your data in the UI automatically, futther more its price is reasonale and you can pay as much as you use.

But as per your requirement you should use SQL, because storing employee data in a RDB is much more maintainable than firebase or any other NoSQL db.